# Google map (mapTypeControlOptions) is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to position my satellite button to the center of the map but however is not working. Would appreciate if anyone can assist here. thanks.

```
function initialize() {
    $(q).addClass('fmp_responsive_map');
    startMap(true);

    var mapProp = {
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
        },

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

    $('input[type="submit"], button[type="submit"]', $(y.searchForm))
        .on('click', function(a) {
            a.preventDefault();
            var b = $(y.searchForm).attr("action");
            searchData(b)
        })
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue. `Uncaught ReferenceError: q is not defined`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: startMap is not defined`, if I fix those (and add the required mapOptions, center and zoom), [the posted code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hq71sp28/) (the map type control is in the top center position)

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Tried the working sample found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning), and made changes to the following code.

```
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 12,
   center: {lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224},
   mapTypeControl: true,
   mapTypeControlOptions: {
   style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.CENTER
},
...
```

That's it. Try using CENTER.